# Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: tensors

Is the Levi-Civita symbol a tensor?

R. A. Sharipov afirm (In "Quick Introduction to Tensor Analysis", page 30) that "...the Levi-Civita symbol is NOT a tensor..."

$\epsilon_{jkq}=\epsilon^{jkq}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl} 0, & \mbox{if among $j$, $k$, $q$ there are at least two equal numbers} \\ 1, & \mbox{if $(j,k,q)$ is even permutation of numbers $(1,2,3)$} \\ -1, & \mbox{if $(j,k,q)$ is odd permutation of numbers} \end{array}\right.$

What does that phrase mean?

Thanks!

Comment: If you define a rank-2 tensor $A$ as an object that transforms as $A_{ij}' = a_{ik} a_{jl} A_{kl}$ then a pseudotensor transforms as $A_{ij}' = J a_{ik} a_{jl} A_{kl}$ where $J = \det A$.  The permutation tensor is a rank-3 pseudotensor, see "Classical Mechanics" by Goldstein for the general form.

Comment: But I need to understand the words of Sharipov in the context of his article [Sharipov](http://samizdat.mines.edu/tensors/ShR6b.pdf) . ¿Does he want to say: "Despite its form or notation will not be a tensor?

Comment: the link to Sharipov's mini-book is broken. I leave here alternative links on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403252), the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226010237/http://samizdat.mines.edu/tensors/ShR6b.pdf), and [this website](https://samizdat.mines.edu/a-quick-introduction-to-tensor-analysis-by-ruslan-sharipov/) hosted by some institute in Colorado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same question and I found this:
http://www.physics.ucc.ie/apeer/PY4112/Tensors.pdf
Page 11, it explains that the Levi-Civita Symbol is a Tensor Density and transforms it using to a tensor the same way that Sharipov did it (and explains the steps).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, please avoid external links in your answer (if one day the link doesn't work, your answer becomes useless).

Comment: The link is now dead, and so is the article of Sharipov