# Proof the Levi-Civita symbol is a tensor

Tags: tensors

A tensor of rank $n$ has components $T_{ij\cdots k}$ (with $n$ indices) with respect to each basis $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ or coordinate system $\{x_i\}$, and satisfies the following rule of change of basis:
        $$
  T_{ij\cdots k}' = R_{ip}R_{jq}\cdots R_{kr}T_{pq\cdots r}.
  $$

Define the Levi-Civita symbol as:
  $$
    \varepsilon_{ijk} =
    \begin{cases}
      +1 & ijk \text{ is even permutation}\\
      -1 & ijk\text{ is odd permutation}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise (ie. repeated suffices)}
    \end{cases}
  $$

Show that $ \varepsilon_{ijk} $ is a rank 3 tensor.

---

I actually have a proof but I can't understand it! Can someone help me out?

$$
 \varepsilon_{ijk}' = R_{ip}R_{jq}R_{kr}\varepsilon_{pqr} = (\det R)\varepsilon_{ijk} = \varepsilon_{ijk},
 $$

This shows that $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ obeys the transformation law, so sure... but I don't follow what happened after the second equals sign

EDIT: Does this only hold for Cartesian coordinate systems, because then $R$ would be an orthogonal matrix with det 1 or -1?

Comment: It is actually a pseudotensor; the Levi-Civita symbol only behaves as a honest affine tensor under proper orthogonal transformations (those with determinant +1).

Comment: [FYR](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771511/levi-civita-symbol?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks [Alex](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/59556/alex-provost) , could you show me where $\det R$ came from, I thought $\det(A) = \varepsilon_{j_1j_2\cdots j_n}A_{j_11}A_{j_22}\cdots A_{j_nn}$... I don't quite see the jump here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $R^i_j$ are the components of the matrix of an orthogonal linear transformation in Euclidean $3$-space, then the general transformation rule for an affine tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ should read $$\epsilon'_{ijk} = R^p_iR^q_j R^r_k \epsilon_{pqr}.$$

Since here $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol, whose values depend not on the coordinate system but only on the numerical indices $i,j,k$ (i.e., $\epsilon' = \epsilon$), this is the same thing as $$\epsilon_{ijk} = R^p_iR^q_j R^r_k \epsilon_{pqr}.$$

Note that since $\epsilon_{pqr}$ vanishes on degenerate multi-indices, the right-hand side only consists of six terms (one for each proper multi-index) and looks like $R^1_iR^2_jR^3_k - R^2_iR^1_jR^3_k + \cdots$. To evaluate this, there are three cases to consider:

- If any two of $i,j,k$ share the same value, then the terms cancel each other pairwise and we get $0$.
- If $ijk$ is an even permutation, then this is just the Leibniz formula for the determinant, and the right-hand side is $\det(R)$.
- If $ijk$ is an odd permutation, then we may swap components pairwise in every term to recover $-\det(R)$ from the previous computation.

Therefore: if $R$ is a *proper* ($\det = 1$) orthogonal transformation, we find that the right-hand side coincides with the left-hand side, and $\epsilon$ behaves like a honest affine tensor of rank $3$. On the other hand, if $R$ is improper ($\det = -1$), we find that $$R^p_iR^q_j R^r_k \epsilon_{pqr} = -\epsilon_{ijk}.$$ This says that the Levi-Civita symbol is not a proper affine tensor but rather a [pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor).

Comment: My understanding is, that the Levi-Civita-symbol is only a pseudotensor with respect to orthogonal transformations. As soon as we admit arbitrary transformations with det(R) not necessarily being equal to +-1, we get this determinant to be the factor in your last equation. But this would violate the definition of a pseudotensor. I think in this general case the Levi-Civita symbol is only a tensor density, that is, a relative tensor of weight 1. See e.g. Anadijiban Das, "Tensors", p.39. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RolandSalz Sounds correct to me!

Comment: Thanks for looking into that after all these years. In fact, I tried to prove the general case $ \epsilon'_{a_1 \dots a_n} = (\det R)^{-1} R^{b_1}_{a_1} \dots R^{b_n}_{a_n} \epsilon_{b_1 \dots b_n} $, but I havn't been able to. That's why I put up another question: [Proof that the Levi-Civita symbol is a tensor density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778998/proof-that-the-levi-civita-symbol-is-a-tensor-density).

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today and this is what I am trying:
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}=det(e_i\ e_j \ e_k)
$$
Let A be an orthogonal transformation, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\epsilon'_{ijk}&\equiv\epsilon_{lmn}=det( e_l \ e_m \ e_n)\\
&=det(Ae_i\ Ae_j \ Ae_k)\\
&=(det(A))^3 det(e_i e_j e_k)\\
&=det(A)\cdot \epsilon_{ijk}\\
&=\pm \epsilon_{ijk}
\end{aligned}
$$
I think this can show that the Levi-Civita is a tensor (or pseudotensor).

Comment: Sorry, I suddenly found that I am not sure whether I can let $\epsilon'_{ijk}\equiv\epsilon_{lmn}$ straightforwardly  :)